# Excel Compare Cells Between Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a macro that compares cells within Column E and if they are found to be matching then it would check/compare the date fields in Column H and the oldest date the macro would mark "yes" in Column R.

I'm newer to excel and not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can't you just sort on columns E and H ?  Your title and question don't seem to be related though, so maybe you missed out some details in your question?

Comment: I was going to take whatever help I get here and apply it to check different workbooks/sheets.

Comment: It's better to decribe up-front what the exact task is, rather than get suggestions which may not be useful in the context of your real problem.

Comment: @user1243498: may I see a sample of your workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are creating a formula on Book1 to compare to Book2, then put this formula in Book1, Column R

```
=IF(E1=[Book2]Sheet1!E1,IF(H1=[Book2]Sheet1!H1,"yes",""),"")
```

Obviously you would need to change the Book Names and Sheet Names.

What did you mean by "Oldest Date"?

Comment: I have a file path in Column E, which should be unique and there should only be one.  So if there is a duplicate path listed in column E, I need to compare the date fields in Column H and the oldest date will need to be removed, so I'll need to put a "yes" in Column R indicating that.

Comment: Are you looking for "any" match of column E in Book2.  In other words could the path from Book1.E3 match Book2.E251 or are you looking for a strict row-by-row match?

btw, as sample of the data and expected results would help.